# How can I modify a MOUSE WHEEL EVENT o a CLICK EVENT on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I've got a simple JQuery image slider which changes slides based on mouse WHEEL rolling. I'd like to modify it so I could change slides based on mouse CLICK events (in this case, over two arrow images, #prevBtn and #nextBtn).

Could anybody help me, please?
Thanks a million!

```js
$flag = true;
$counter = 1;

$(window).on('wheel', function(event){

 if($flag)
 {
  $flag = false;
  if(event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0)
  {
   // EXECUTE ON MOUSE WHEEL DOWN

   $counter++;

   if($counter==1)
    $counter++;

   if($counter==2)
   {
    $(".colorbox1").animate({'top':'-100%'});
    $(".colorbox2").animate({'top':'0%'});
    $(".red_info").animate({'top':'-100%'},700);
    $(".orange_info").animate({'top':'0%'},700);
    $(".img1").animate({'top':'-50%'},700);
    $(".img2").animate({'top':'50%'},700);

   }

   if($counter==3)
   {
    $(".colorbox2").animate({'top':'-100%'});
    $(".colorbox3").animate({'top':'0%'});
    $(".orange_info").animate({'top':'-100%'},700);
    $(".green_info").animate({'top':'0%'},700);
    $(".img2").animate({'top':'-50%'},700);
    $(".img3").animate({'top':'50%'},700);

   }

   if($counter > 3)
    $counter = 3;
  }
  else {

// EXECUTE ON MOUSE WHEEL UP

   $counter--;
   if($counter <= 1)
    $counter = 1;
   if($counter == 2)
   {
    $(".colorbox3").animate({'top':'100%'});
    $(".colorbox2").animate({'top':'0%'});
    $(".green_info").animate({'top':'100%'},700);
    $(".orange_info").animate({'top':'0%'},700);
    $(".img3").animate({'top':'150%'},700);
    $(".img2").animate({'top':'50%'},700);
 
   }
   if($counter == 1)
   {
    $(".colorbox2").animate({'top':'100%'});
    $(".colorbox1").animate({'top':'0%'});
    $(".orange_info").animate({'top':'100%'},700);
    $(".red_info").animate({'top':'0%'},700);
    $(".img2").animate({'top':'150%'},700);
    $(".img1").animate({'top':'50%'},700);
 
   }
   if($counter == 3)
    $counter--;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){$flag = true;},500);
 }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 120%;
}
.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  width: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}
.img2,
.img3 {
  top: 150%;
}
.box2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.colorbox1,
.colorbox2,
.colorbox3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.colorbox2 {
  background-color: orange;
  top: 100%;
}
.colorbox3 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  top: 100%;
}
#prevBtn {
  height: 5vh;
  cursor: pointer;  
  position: absolute;
  right: 350px;
  top: 390px;
}
#nextBtn {
  height: 5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 380px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="test mobile.css">
</head>
<body>

 <img src="Images/1.png" alt="" class="img1">
 <img src="Images/2.png" alt="" class="img2">
 <img src="Images/3.png" alt="" class="img3">

 <div class="box2">
  <div class="colorbox1"></div>
  <div class="colorbox2"></div>
  <div class="colorbox3"></div>

 </div>

 <img src="Images/Arrow Left.svg" alt="" id="prevBtn">
 <img src="Images/Arrow Right.svg" alt="" id="nextBtn">



 <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test mobile.js"></script>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the code from the `wheel` handler and transfer it to a new function:

```
moveImage(next) {
  if ($flag) {
    $flag = false;
    if (next) {
      ...
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
    setTimeout(function(){$flag = true;},500);
}
```

Then replace the code on wheel handler with this new function:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(event){
  moveImage(event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0);
}
```

And add new handlers for the click event:

```
$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
  moveImage(false);
});

$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  moveImage(true);
});
```